# How to detect change in colours in the image below?

Tags: python, opencv

I need to identify the pixels where there is a change in colour. I googled for edge detection and line detection techniques but am not sure how or in what way can these be applied.

Here are my very naive attempts:

- Applying `Canny Edge Detection`

  ```
   edges = cv2.Canny(img,0,10)
  ```

with various parameters but it didn't work

- Applying `Hough Line Transform` to detect lines in the document

The intent behind this exercise is that I have an ill-formed table of values in a pdf document with the background I have attached. If I am able to identify the row boundaries using colour matching as in this question, my problem will be reduced to identifying columns in the data.

[image]

Comment: Where is your attempt to do this? Are you really asking us to just write the code for you? If so how are we even suppose to know what you want as a final result?

Comment: My apologies. I have elaborated on my attempts at solving the question, and have also provided on my intent. Hope this make the question more valuable to the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to image processing. What you're trying to do here is basically trying to find the places where the change in color between neighboring pixels is big, thus where the derivative of pixel intensities in the y direction is substantial. In signal processing, those are called high frequencies. The most common detector for high frequencies in images is called Canny Edge Detector and you can find a [very nice tutorial here, on the OpenCV website](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/da/d22/tutorial_py_canny.html).

The algorithm is very easy to implement and requires just a few simple steps:

```
import cv2

# load the image
img = cv2.imread("sample.png")
# convert to grayscale
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
# resize for the visualization purposes
img = cv2.resize(img, None, img, fx=0.4, fy=0.4)
# find edges with Canny
edges = cv2.Canny(img, 10, 20, apertureSize=3)
# show and save the result
cv2.imshow("edges", edges)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.imwrite("result.png", edges)
```

Since your case is very straightforward you don't have to worry about the parameters in the Canny() function call. But if you choose to find out what they do, I recommend checking out [how to implement a trackbar](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/threshold/threshold.html) and use it for experimenting. The result:

[image]

Good luck.